# How to play mp3 file android w/ mediaplayer if files in same directory as activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've personally never liked how Android implements fetching local resources but this is one I can't work around for some odd reason. The mp3 files are in the same package as the MainActivity so how can I play them using the media player? I've resorted to stackoverflow because I keep seeing other posts and the answer is always referring to something that does not exist in my case "R.raw.*".. Any help would be appreciated.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(MainActivity.class.getResource("file.mp3").getPath());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

When I use that code nothing happens, I believe it's because I can't just simply fetch the audio file like you could in any other Java implementation - android always seems to be very pedantic and tedious.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the samples from the Android documentation? The very same sample uses local files… I personally never liked the questions that complain about the technology. If you don't like Android this is not the right place to complain. ;)

Comment: Inside code add these mp3 files to assets folder. While at time of installing application copy all files from Assets to device from first activity. Then you can play files from local device.

Comment: I have read the documentation. All I've found was how the mediaplayer can be used to play audio files etc. all the examples that I seen over (I admit brief period of time) didn't show any real path to an mp3 file. There was no string that specifically said the path. Just a vague reference to something that I don't know of.

Comment: Oh, I got this to work. This was idiocy on my part. 
Tiredness is a struggle. Thanks for the replies anyway. 
I ended up using the assets directory with a file descriptor. Thanks gu